# Comparing Array sizes of different types in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I want to create a method that validates that two Arrays are of same length like:

```
validateSameSize(Object[] first, Object[] second) {
   if (first.length != second.length) throw new Exception();
}
```

The problem is that this method only works for non-primitive Arrays. If I want to compare a `char`-Array with another array this does not work. Is there a way to implement this function without too much overhead?

I have already tried

```
<T,V> validateSameSize(T[] first, V[] second)
```

but since generics also need a class and don't work with primitive types, this does not work. Also

```
validateSameSize(Array first, Array second)
```

doesn't work either

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Array#getLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength-java.lang.Object-):

```
public static boolean sameSize(Object arrayA, Object arrayB) {
    return Array.getLength(arrayA) == Array.getLength(arrayB);
}
```

It will work with non-primitive arrays as well as with primitive ones:

```
System.out.println(sameSize(new int[0], new int[100])); // false
System.out.println(sameSize(new char[0], new int[0])); // true
System.out.println(sameSize(new Object[0], new Object[0])); // true
System.out.println(sameSize(new Object[0], new List[0])); // true
```

---

Also don't forget that passing an `Object` that is not an array to `Array#getLength` will result in `IllegalArgumentException`.

This code:

```
Object notArray = 100;
System.out.println(Array.getLength(notArray));
```

produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array
```

---

If you need to fail fast before invoking `Array#getLength` you can check if the argument is *actually* array:

```
if (!object.getClass().isArray()) {
  // object is not array. Do something with it
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So just for clarification: a primitive Array does not inherit from ```Object[]```, but a primitive value does inherit from ```Object```?

Comment: No, primitive types do not take part in inheritance at all. An `int` is not an object, it is just the number. The Java Language Specification probably has a chapter called Primitive Types, which would be the definitive source on this topic.

Comment: @Schottky Every Java array is an `Object`, whether its elements are `Object`s or not.

Answer (score 3):

The caco3 answer is fine.
Note that if the `Object` params are not arrays you will discover it only at runtime.
A safer way would be to overload the method for primitives :

```
void validateSameSize(Object[] first, Object[] second) throws Exception {
    if (first.length != second.length) throw new Exception();
}

void validateSameSize(int[] first, int[] second) throws Exception {
    if (first.length != second.length) throw new Exception();
}
```

And so for...
It will require you to write more code but your code would be more robust.